# System.InvalidOperationException in Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus.dll

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I have a Azure Function (v2) that I would like to trigger against a service bus queue:

```
[FunctionName("ConsumeNewClient")]
        public async void EntryPoint([ServiceBusTrigger(queueName:LocalSettings.AvaloqServiceBusConfigurationValues.Queue,
            Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")]
            string ceSbMsg, [OrchestrationClient] DurableOrchestrationClient starter, ILogger log)
        {
            var instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync("PolicyOrchestrator", ceSbMsg);
            _logger.LogInformation(0, $"[Interfaces.Avaloq.Presentation.AzureFunctions.ConsumeNewClient] - Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.");
    }
```

When I debug from VS2019 I get the following message in the Output\Debug window several times:

*Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus.dll*

The app continues until I place a message on the monitored queue (using service bus explorer) then I get the same exception another several times. I've set a breakpoint on the *var instanceId = ...* but this breakpoint is never hit.

If I copy the same function and paste into an older solution (along with  then entry for ServiceBusConnection into local.settings.json) then everything works fine.

Does anyone know of a way to get more detailed info about the exception that is being thrown in Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus.dll?

Answer (score 0):

Use `async Task` instead of `async void`

```
[FunctionName("ConsumeNewClient")]
public async Task EntryPoint(
        [ServiceBusTrigger(queueName:LocalSettings.AvaloqServiceBusConfigurationValues.Queue, Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")]
        string ceSbMsg, 
        [OrchestrationClient] 
        DurableOrchestrationClient starter, 
        ILogger log) {
    var instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync("PolicyOrchestrator", ceSbMsg);
    _logger.LogInformation(0, $"[Interfaces.Avaloq.Presentation.AzureFunctions.ConsumeNewClient] - Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.");
}
```

the async void is most likely causing a fire and forget which throws the exception because of threading issues.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by the fact that I had failed to register a service (Mediatr) with the DI container. I was able to identify this by downloading the source code for Service Bus and stepping through with the VS debugger.